# How can I write a shell completion hook for a multi-word prefix?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, bash-completion, zsh-completion

Let's say I want to write a custom shell completion function that fires only on `git checkout <tab>`. I can write a custom hook for `git` completion like this:

```
complete -f -F _custom_completion_function git   # bash
compctl -f -K _custom_completion_function git    # zsh
```

But that will overwrite *all* of my existing `git` bash/zsh completion; I only want to change the behavior of `git checkout`.

What's the best strategy for achieving this?

Comment: A very simple solution consists in defining an alias of `git checkout`, add the compspec you want for the alias and use the alias instead of `git checkout`.

Comment: I'm not sure the `bash` and `zsh` solutions will be similar enough to warrant including both in the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on your existing git completion setup. Chances are this already checks the first word on the command-line when deciding what to do. Can't it just call a separate function if that first word is "checkout".

For zsh, I'd recommend not using the ancient compctl completion system. If you use the newer system (by running `autoload -U compinit; compinit`), then the git completion included with zsh allows you to define your own `_git-checkout` function. Define that and it'll take precedence over the one zsh includes.